# export yajra datatable all data to csv

Tags: csv, jquery-plugins, datatable, datatables, export-to-csv

I'm not able to find any solution for saving all the records to CSV using yajra datatables.

Currently i'm getting paginated records that are displaying on current screen (10 records), what i need is all the records

I'm using yajra datatables buttons extension.

My current code is :

```
    $('#export-table').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    responsive: true,
    autoWidth:false,
    aaSorting: [[6, 'desc']],
    ajax: '{!! route('export.data') !!}',
    aoColumns: [
        {mData:'name', name: 'name'},
        {mData:'address', name: 'address'},
        {mData:'phone', name: 'phone'},
        {mData:'cell_phone', name: 'cell_phone'},
        {mData:'email', name: 'm.email'},
        {mData:'company', name: 'company'},
        {mData:'date_taken', name: 'date_taken'}
    ],
    buttons: ['csv']
});
```

Need help to save all records to csv

**UPDATE**

I'm using yajra datatables plugin with laravel 5.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a day long try, i was able to resolve my question and the answer is to change serverSide option value from true to false.

```
serverSide: false
```

It may help someone

Comment: This is not correct way to do. If you make serverSide: false then if your table have lot's of records then it will be stop working in if you don't want server side then no need to integrate yajra at all. use simple data-table it will be work for you.

Comment: When you stop serverSide it will load all the data at first time and serverSide:true load in only initial data and on the every event they called ajax and fetch dynamic data.

Comment: Not practical at all

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

Add Javascript library for buttons from this link.
https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html

```
 $('#user_datatable').DataTable({
        // dom: 'Bfrtip',
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        responsive: true,
        autoWidth:false,
        ajax: '{{ route("admin.ajax.list.user") }}',


        columns: [
        { data: 'id', name: 'id' },
        { data: 'name', name: 'name' },
        { data: 'roles', name: 'roles' },
        { data: 'admin_status', name: 'admin_status' },
        { data: 'action', name: 'action' },
        ],

        dom: 'lBfrtip',
        buttons: [
          'excel', 'csv', 'pdf', 'copy'
        ],
        "lengthMenu": [ [10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"] ]


});
```

Comment: This does not address the question asked.